# broadcastreceiver for file creation on sdcard in android?

Tags: android, file-io, broadcastreceiver

broadcastreceiver for file creation on sdcard in android?
i want to my app run when new file is created on SD-card.
is there any broadcastreceiver for file creation?or other ways?

another program creates files and i need to know new file is created and its file path.
like receiver for boot complete or wifichange or location.

```
<application
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

   <receiver android:name="MyReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
      </action>
      </intent-filter>
   </receiver>

</application>
```

Comment: You probable want a `FileObserver`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use AlarmManager to periodically scan the directory for changes using [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html), with a polling period, so they can control battery and CPU consumption by your app.

Comment: do you have any sample code?or link that do more help about file change and application know that change?